# Put Text in a Small Button

Tags: asp.net, css

```
.buttonVehicle{float:right; height:15px; padding:none; margin:none; text-align:center; text-indent:0; text-decoration:none; text-transform:none;}
```

The button appears now but not with any text inside it.

```
<asp:button id="btn" runat="server" CssClass="buttonVehicle" Text="..." />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the font size small enough to fit within the button I.e. font-size:8px; and the line height to an appropriate height for the font, I usually do 2px larger than the font so line-height:10px;.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the height of the button is too short.

The text is actually apearing below the button. You'll notice that if you set the height to something like 35px, the text shows again.

Comment: This is true but I need the button to be that small. Can I change the text alignment to be the top or something?

Comment: The only thing I can think of right now that brings the text into view is setting the font-size to 8px;. This makes for some small dots but still, they're in view.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a button that small, you could make your own image that looks like your desired button, and then use `asp:ImageButton`. Just a thought

Comment: The text may change so I can't do that. A valid attempt though :)

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the padding and margin attributes in the style to 0px instead of none.